# Name of a scientist in Doom Patrol who gives people superpowers for the right price

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe

This character appeared in the first season of Doom Patrol- a scientist who hid somewhere in South America (he might have been a Nazi war criminal), and people (including the man who became the villain Mr. Nobody) sought him out and paid him to alter their bodies to give them superhuman abilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for [Henreich Von Fuchs](https://doompatrol.fandom.com/wiki/Heinrich_Von_Fuchs).

> After the war, Heinrich Von Fuchs moved to Paraguay (allegedly "for health reasons") and adopted the alias of "Señor Martinez", a so-called village cobbler. However, he continued his "theoretical experimentation" on humans, which attracted the attention of a man known as Mr. Eric Morden.
>
> In exchange for "something of great value," Von Fuchs subjected him to a procedure that would later be named "The Morden". Von Fuchs instructed Morden to repeat the phrase "the mind is the limit", as he exposed Morden to an unknown energy in a chamber. This was supposed to attract metahuman powers from alternate dimensions, though the details are unknown. Before the experiment was finished, however, he was interrupted and shot by Niles Caulder, who proceeded to steal Morden's payment from Von Fuchs. However, the procedure was a success, and Eric Morden was christened Mr. Nobody.

He was almost certainly based off of [Dr. Bruckner](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/doctor-bruckner/4005-67853/) from the comics, who held the same role of empowering Mr. Nobody.

Found with a search for `doom patrol nazi`